# Does $\rho>0$ imply $P(X>a,Y>a)$$>$$P(X>a) P(Y>a)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider two stochastic variables X and Y that are distributed $N(0, \sigma_1)$ and $N(0, \sigma_2)$ and are correlated $\rho>0$.

Is it true that $P(X>a,Y>a)>P(X>a)$$P(Y>a)$?
Does the answer depend on whether $a>0$ or $a<0$?

I have tried to find the answer to the solution by starting with the definition of the correlation coefficient, $\rho>0$. This provides me with $E(XY)$$>$$E(X)$$E(Y)$. However, after this I am stuck.

Any help or hint is much appreciated.

Comment: is it >a>a or >a>b your title and question are contradictory

Comment: it depends on the whether the variables are dependent or independent

Comment: @David L Thanks for the pointer, I edited the title.

Comment: @David L The variables are positively correlated with each other. With that I wanted to say that they are dependent.

Comment: are you looking for a simple is it true or a proof?

Comment: If there is a proof I would be grateful to see it. If you know a reference where I can read it I would also be grateful.

Comment: I'll try and look for a proof, but this is generally how i see it. Since a positive correlation implies that as x > a, then y > a is more likely in a joint distribution. Thus, p(x>a,y>a) should be greater than the respective marginal distributions multiplied

Comment: Why do you accept a post which does not answer the question you asked, which makes it clear that it is not an answer but that it provides some complements to the answer posted (providing these complements being a quite nice thing to do, if you ask me)?

Comment: @Did I am not sure whether your last comment refers to me accepting Sinusx' answer. I did not want to violate any rule. The reason I accepted the answer is because it complements your answer very well in making clear that it spells out an implicit assumption I made that I was not even aware of. Namely that I assumed a jointly Gaussian distribution. I understand that you realized this. But for an amateur like me Sinusx' answer provided a helpful insight.   By the way, I am really impressed by your mathematical skills! I have learned so much these last two months from your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume without loss of generality that $\sigma^2_2\geqslant\sigma_1^2$ and note that 
$$Y=(\sigma_2\rho/\sigma_1)\cdot X+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\cdot Z,
$$ where $Z$ is normal $(0,\sigma_2^2)$ and independent of $X$. Furthermore, $\rho\geqslant0$ hence, if
$X\gt a$ and $Z\gt a$, then $Y\gt\theta a$,
where
$$
\theta=(\sigma_2\rho/\sigma_1)+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\geqslant\rho+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\geqslant1.
$$
Thus, if $a\gt0$ then $\theta a\geqslant a$ hence
$$
P(X\gt a)P(Y\gt a)=P(X\gt a,Z\gt a)\leqslant P(X\gt a,Y\gt\theta a)\leqslant P(X\gt a,Y\gt a).
$$
Finally the inequality is strict because $\theta\gt1$ except when $\rho=0$ (but this case is excluded) and $\rho=1$ (but then $Y=\sigma_2 X/\sigma_1$ and a direct argument works).

Comment: @Stefanos Listen, I do not know what you are smoking and frankly, I am not interested. Comment flagged.

Comment: @Stefanos: Hence, furthermore, thus, etc. are very commonly used transitions in mathematical writing.  This is because these are very clear in their meaning and express subtle indications of the importance of the stages of deduction (furthermore, for instance, indicates that besides conclusion A there is another, possibly not dependent on A, conclusion B from current premises).  Thus begins a deductive thought, whereas hence is a deduction.  We use these to understand the argument better.  It is weird on a math site to see "WHY YOU TRY TALK SMART??"

Answer (score 1):

From the formula of conditional probability we have that $$P(X>a|Y>a)=\frac{P(X>a,Y>a)}{P(Y>a)}$$ (There is no problem to divide by $P(Y>a)$, since normal probability distribution gives positive probabality to every interval. That is also why the precise value of a, i.e. whether positive or negative, does not affect your answer). Since $X,Y$ are positively correlated we have that $$P(X>a|Y>a)>P(X>a)$$ As David L intuitively stated, the positive correlation implies that when $Y>a$ it is more likely that also $X>a$ compared to when we have no information about $Y$ (in other words $X,Y$ are smaller together and bigger together). Combining the two equations $$\frac{P(X>a,Y>a)}{P(Y>a)}>P(X>a) \implies P(X>a,Y>a)>P(Y>a)P(X>a)$$ we receive the result.

Comment: "Since X,Y are positively correlated we have that
P(X>a|Y>a)>P(X>a)" Hmmm... why?

Comment: because that is what positively correlated means

Comment: @DavidL Not. At. All. Please check the definition.

Comment: @Did http://mste.illinois.edu/courses/ci330ms/youtsey/GRAPH1.GIF - given Y>a, what can you say about X>a?

Comment: @DavidL Dear David, which part of "Please check the definition" do you fail to understand?

Comment: @did Maybe you should provide us the definition you are using?

Comment: @DavidL Right, if one does not know [the definition of correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence), suddenly this explains some comments here.

Comment: @did explain to me why positive linear dependence does not suggest P(X>a|Y>a)>P(X>a)

Comment: @DavidL Because this is WRONG. Comment flagged.

Comment: @did right, because in order to prove something is wrong, all i have to do is write WRONG in capital letter. how about presenting your reasoning behind saying it is wrong with more than just "the definition states it is wrong?" for example, a counter example of which it is not true?

Comment: @DavidL Since this is a matter of checking the definition (and well known, to say the least), you are just showing you did not even care to check the link I provided. What more is there to say?

Comment: @Stefanos Thanks for your answer.  However, I do not see how the definition of   $\rho=Cov(X,Y)/$$\sigma_X \sigma_Y$   implies  $P(X>a|Y>a)$$>$$P(X>a)$  Can you prove that?

Comment: @DavidL: Unfortunately, your claim is incorrect.  In simple mental models, sure you can come up with distributions that work.  But such models are simple because they have the same behaviors over their range.  It is easy to find counterexamples where the behavior changes at some point (maybe 'a') and still is correlated over the distribution.  This is likely why Did is pointing you to the definition and pointing out the hand waving.

Comment: @drcms02 Your welcome. I feel responsible for the fact that the conversation is gone awry in your post, so I am sorry. No, I do not have a proof. I Actually based my answer on the following link (page 24/25) http://courses.umass.edu/pubp608/lectures/l3.pdf. and on the fact that the normal random variables give positive probability to every interval. Then I thought that the result was intuitive from that point on.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not assume, that $X$ and $Y$ have jointly Gaussian distribution, then the inequality $P(X>a,Y>a)>P(X>a)P(Y>a)$ need not hold, even if $X$ and $Y$ are positively correlated.

For example, let $\sigma_1 =1$ , and for $X$ with distribution $N(0,1)$ take

$$Y=I_{\{|X| \leq n\}}X  -  I_{\{|X| > n\}}X.$$ Then $Y$ has Gaussian law $N(0,1)$, and $\text{E} XY  >0$ for big enough $n$. However,

$$P(X>n,Y>n)  =  0 < P(X>n)P(Y>n)$$

If $X$ and $Y$ have jointly Gaussian distribution, then the way of reasoning provided by Did seems to be correct.

Comment: "Seems to be correct"? My Lord is too nice...

Comment: If |X| is less than n, then Y is less than n. If |X| is greater than n then Y is less than -n. So Y can never take values greater than n, and therefore I do not think that Y is Gaussian. Besides if P(Y>n)=0 as I claim, then your inequality P(X>n,Y>n)=0<P(X>n)P(Y>n) does not hold, because both sides are equal to zero. Probably I miss something...

Comment: To Did: I am sorry if I did not express myself quite correctly, I just wanted to say that your answer is correct in my opinion, assuming  jointly Gaussian distribution.

Comment: To Stefanos: If $X < -n $, then $Y > n$.

Comment: @Sinusx Yes, ok, true.